# Why my pointer variable is holding different address and still pointing to variable successfully?

Tags: c++, pointers

**Code:**

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num = 10, *p;
    *p = num;
    cout<<" &num = "<<&num<<" p = "<<p<<endl<<" *p = "<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
&num = 0x7ffeef0908c8 p = 0x7ffeef0908e0
 *p = 10
```

Theoretically content of 'p' is equal to the address of 'num'. But it's not happening here.
But still, it's pointing 'num' successfully.
Why?

Comment: You need to initialize `p` correctly before you do `*p  = num;`(aka dereferencing it). You code has _undefined behavior_, any attempt to explain that behavior would be totally futile.

Comment: `'p' is equal to the address of 'num'` No, for that you would need to do `p = &num;` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is UB.  It may look as if it worked,  but could as well corrupt or crash the system, or anything else (usually bad) could happen.

```
 int num = 10, *p; // this leaves p unitialized; you don't know to what it points
 *p = num;         // OUCH!  This is UB because you dereference an unitialized pointer
```

Here a working alternative:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num = 10, *p;
    p = &num;    // make the pointer point to to num using the address
    cout<<"&num = "<<&num<<" num = "<<num<<" p = "<<p<<" *p = "<<*p<<endl;
    *p = 77;     // change the value pointed to
    cout<<"&num = "<<&num<<" num = "<<num<<" p = "<<p<<" *p = "<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whooo! Pointers are pretty complex. Thank you so much for explanation.